# Effect of a binary variable on the ranks in multiple ordinal leaderboards

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ordinal-data

Consider that we have a game that results in an ordinal leaderboard.
Now, play $N$ rounds of that game, with different number of players.
I want to know if a nominal attribute of the players has an effect on their ranks.

Let's have a minimal example. We play just $N=5$ rounds of that game.
Let our nominal attribute be the gender of our players.
The two columns denote the ranks of female and male players, respectively.

```py
#   FEMALE ranks --  MALE ranks  --  N

x = [[      (2,),         (1,) ],  # 1
     [ (3, 4, 7), (1, 2, 5, 6) ],  # 2
     [    (1, 4),    (2, 3, 5) ],  # 3
     [ (2, 3, 5),       (1, 4) ],  # 4
     [    (1, 3),    (2, 4, 5) ]]  # 5
```

**Are male or female players better at this game?**

I thought about using ranks that start at zero, computing the mean rank in each cell, normalizing that by the number of players in that round and performing a t-test.
However, this feels arbitrary and not correct.

```
n  female  male
1    1.00  0.00
2    0.61  0.42
3    0.38  0.58
4    0.58  0.38
5    0.25  0.67
```

One more thing that I had one my mind was that I do a Mann-Whitney U test for each round, and combine the $N$ p-values that I obtained with Fisher's combined probability test.
Feels better but I am not sure if I can combine p-values like that.

Do you know what kind of null hypothesis and test fits such a problem?